# Convert a 2 Dimentional array to a single dimention

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array 
( 
[0] => Array 
       ( 
       [25] => 21.00 
       )
[1] => Array 
       ( 
       [33] => 63.00 
       ) 
 )
```

and i want to make it like this:

```
Array (
      [25] => 21.00 
      [33] => 63.00 
      )
```

Is there a build in function that i can use or any idea of something else?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it guaranteed there are no conflicting keys in the two arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$output = [];
foreach($input as $subArray) {
   foreach($subArray as $k=>$v) {
      $output[$k] = $v;
   }
}
```